# Sublime text keymap: Switch to tab number [NUM] in rubymine

Tags: sublimetext3, rubymine, keymapping

I have recently switched from sublime text 3 to rubymine which is of great benefit. But i am missing one functionality. In sublime text command + [NUM] would switch to tab number [NUM]. but in rubymine i cant seem to find an action similar to this in the keymap section of preferences. I would be happy if someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such shortcut in RubyMine; in general, tab numbers are not considered significant in JetBrains products. As an alternative, you can use keybindings that allow you to switch to a tab by typing the first few characters of the filename, such as Ctrl-Tab and Cmd-E.

Comment: The `cmd+shif+O` (open file by name), `cmd+O` (open file by class name), and `cmd+shift+A` (Find RubyMine actions) are also helpful shortcuts. I learned a lot from this talk from RailsConf 2016 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=issom99iWDs